Can you help me with playing "Spotify" in terminal?
I'm looking for some help with setting up Spotify on my terminal using a free Spotify account. Previously, there had been some configurations that worked, but it seems like they no longer do for free accounts.
How can I configure mopidy along with ncmpcpp to listen to Spotify in the terminal using a free Spotify account? I'm hoping to set up mopidy alongside ncmpcpp to play songs on the terminal, as this method uses less memory compared to the web player via a browser. I'm trying to minimize RAM usage while I work with Cursor and other applications. If anyone has a working setup or can provide guidance on how to achieve this, I'd greatly appreciate it.
Thanks in advance for your help! 
